# SparkSQL MS SQL Server , Get message "No suitable driver" After compiled

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**build.sbt**

```
name := "BigData"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.3.5"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "6.1.0.jre8" % Test
```

**SparkMSSQL.scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkMSSQL {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.
      builder.master("local[*]")
      .appName("Simple Application")
      .getOrCreate()
    val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=scalatest;integratedSecurity=true";
    // Define database table to load into DataFrame
    val jdbcDbTable = "dbo.user_profiles"
    val df = spark
      .read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", url)
      .option("dbtable", "dbo.user_profiles")
      .load()

    df.printSchema()
  }
}
```

Error after compile

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$2(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
```

Please advice , what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have your jdbc driver in the `test` scope, so the jar is probably not loaded at runtime. But also, spark needs driver class information to create JDBC connection, so try adding the following option to the DF initializer:

```
.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
```